# Correlation Coefficient vs Coefficient of Determination

Tags: regression

I am doing regression analysis on two stocks. The correlation coefficient is -0.7190 and the coefficient of determination is 0.5170. I am confused on how to interpret this. Is this correct...when stock A goes up 1%, 50% of the time stock B will go down 0.72%?

Comment: not directly related to the question so a mere remark; beware, from a practitioner point of view, using Pearson correlation is usually not a good idea to measure association between two stocks

Answer (score 5):

The usual way of interpreting the coefficient of determination $R^{2}$ is as the percentage of the variation of the dependent variable $y$ $(Var(y))$ that one is able to explain with the explanatory variables. You can find the exact interpretation and derivation of the coefficient of determination $R^{2}$ on this [Economic Theory Blog](http://economictheoryblog.com/2014/11/05/the-coefficient-of-determination-latex-r2) website.

However, a less known interpretation of the coefficient of determination $R^{2}$ is to interpret it as the Squared Pearson Correlation Coefficient between the observed values $y_{i}$ and the fitted values $\hat{y}_{i}$. You can find the proof that the coefficient of determination is the equivalent of the Squared Pearson Correlation Coefficient between the observed values $y_{i}$ and the fitted values $\hat{y}_{i}$ on this [Economic Theory Blog](http://economictheoryblog.com/2014/11/05/proof) website.

Comment: +1: It's worth mentioning that $R$ is referred as the multiple correlation coefficient.

Comment: This is helpful but dependent on an external site. If that blog site were to disappear, the answer would lose much of its value. I don't know about "less known". I'd regard it as standard to explain up front that they are one and the same in plain regression. Many people are taught regression after correlation, so emphasis on the link is then natural. (Whether that's a good thing can be set on one side.)

Answer (score 3):

If you do a regression $y=\beta_1 x + \beta_2$ (so with one independent variable), then the squared of the correlation coefficient is equal to the coefficient of determination.  So (-0.7190)^2 is around 0.5170 (rounding errors).

The coeffcient of determination tells you that 51.7% of the variance in the dependent variable $y$ is explained by the regression.

if $x$ goes up by one unit, then $y$ goes up by $\beta_1$ units. $\beta_1$ can be estimated using ordinary least squares and can be found in the output of R function

```
summary(lm(y~x))
```

So e.g.

```
reg <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
summary (reg)
```

yields

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7121 -2.1122 -0.8854  1.5819  8.2360 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 30.09886    1.63392  18.421  < 2e-16 ***
hp          -0.06823    0.01012  -6.742 1.79e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.863 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6024,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5892 
F-statistic: 45.46 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.788e-07
```

So if $hp$ increases by one unit, then $mpg$ decreases (decrease because negative sign) by 0.06823.

The coefficient of determination is $R^2=0.6024$ and (there is only one independent variable) the correlation is -0.776 (square root of 0.6024 and the sign is negative because the coefficient of hp is negative (-0.06823) ).

Comment: +1. I suspect you meant to write "one *independent* variable" every place that "one *dependent* variable" appears.

Comment: @whuber: you are right, it must be 'independent variable' of course, I changed it in the text and give (+1) for correcting the error

Comment: The psychology of this terminology is interesting--I frequently make the same mistake.  I have taken to using the term "response variable" instead of "dependent variable" in order to avoid confusing myself and others by the similarity of "dependent" and "independent" (although I worry about implying a causal relationship). I also like "explanatory" instead of "independent," but a client recently objected to that terminology (even in the form "potential explanatory variable") because the coefficients were insignificant--and so the variables were considered not "explanatory"!

Comment: Further objections to "dependent" and "Independent" are that the terms are overloaded and in any case are so close that beginning students (and indeed others) can easily get confused between them. Since 2015 when @whuber wrote I think "response" has held up well as good terminology in several fields, but is also being challenged by "outcome".  Either term seems excellent to me.

Comment: @Nick Many times after initially writing "outcome" I withdraw that term in favor of "response" out of concern it could (validly) be considered to be the entire vector of observed values in any observational setting.  In effect, "outcome" does not adequately distinguish the explanatory from the response variables.

Comment: There is no contradiction here. You prefer to avoid the term but it's still very popular. I hate, for example, DV and IV as abbreviations and would never, ever use them (except like this) but that's had no detectable effect on their use by others, nor would I expect to have any leverage there. I've had tiny success in persuading people in my circles to avoid "dummy variable", which is all too likely to be misinterpreted.